# Connect to a peer inside a Carrier-based NAT(and a home NAT) from outside?

Tags: networking, p2p, bittorrent

Are there any ways to establish a p2p connections among peers behind Carrier-grade NATs? 
Do I have to use a middle server to initiate the connection? 
Are there any other ways?
How BitTorrent do establish a p2p connection in such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to use a middle server to initiate the connection?

You don't need a *server*, any mutually reachable peer in a p2p network can act as rendezvous.

> Are there any ways to establish a p2p connections among peers behind Carrier-grade NATs?

If the CGNAT uses Endpoint-Independent Mappings (EIM) as suggested by [RFC 6888](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6888) and others then regular NAT traversal techniques apply.

> Are there any other ways?

Some home routers support nat-pmp/pcp and forward that to the cgnat.

> How BitTorrent do establish a p2p connection in such a situation?

See my answer on [How NAT traversal works in case of peer to peer protocols like bittorrent.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37368417/1362755)