# python bittorrent peer protocol unable to connect to any peers

Tags: python, sockets, bittorrent

I"m trying to learn more about bittorrent protocols, and i'm successful in obtaining a list of peers via UDP.

Where I am having trouble with, is making a connection to the peer IPs itself (even before sending a handshake). i'm usually met with errors such as: `A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

I've read up as much as I could, and according to most documentations:

> After receiving a peer IP and port-number from the tracker, our client will to open a TCP connection to that peer. Once the connection is open, these peers will start to exchange messages using the peer protocol.

However, I don't think this is as simple as

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ip, port))  # where ip and port is obtained from the list of IPs and PORTS from the tracker
## This above 2 lines of codes is met with a connection attempt failed error.
```

According to this [p2p question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367769/how-nat-traversal-works-in-case-of-peer-to-peer-protocols-like-bittorrent/37368417#37368417), there is a bunch of low level things that will need to be done in order for me to connect to the list of peers i've obtained from the `UDP announce` trackers.

How should I go about in making a connection to the peers?

Answer (score 0):

You can read this : http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html.

If you want to make a connection, you need to connect by peer protocol / peer wire protocol. So you need to use utp or TCP, the pure UDP can not work. And the message format need to follow protocols.